# Accessing GetComponent() without instantiating

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am new to Unity Game Development and I find the following usage in code a bit confusing.

```
private Transform enemy;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    enemy = GetComponent<Transform>();
}
```

According to the documentation GetComponent() is a public function. So how can this be accessed without being instantiated?
I found a similar question was asked on Unity's community but I didn't find any of the answers answering the question exactly to the point. Please help me in understanding this.
The link to question on Unity forum is below.
[Question](https://answers.unity.com/questions/971163/accessing-getcomponent-without-instantiating.html)

My Unity version is 2018.4.16f1
Thanks!

Comment: It’s a method in the class you’re calling it so the object already exists

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen So that means I can use any non-static method in the class similarly? without instantiation?

Comment: You can use any method in that class (or the ones allowed by its parents) since there already is an instance since it’s not called from a static method itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class most probably inherits from [`MonoBehaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) which inherits from [`Behaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Behaviour.html) which inherits from [`Component`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.html).

`Component` implements [`GetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponent.html)

Fazit: The instance which you are calling this method on is no other than `this`, the instance `Start` is called on.

---

Btw for `Transform` there is already a dedicated property [`Component.transform`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-transform.html) so you should not use `GetComponent` for getting a `Transform` reference.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response! So I suppose I can use any non-static method from a parent class inside a child life cycle method?

Comment: @bhagya well, yes, that's how c# and object oriented programming in general works :)

Comment: :) yeah just needed the confirmation. thnx!

Answer (score 1):

you are calling the GetComponent() method of the GameObject you added your MonoBehavior to and assign it to the Transform enemy. It is even the first Answer from your linked Question.